# IIS8 PHP7 multiple php websites

Tags: iis-8, php7

I'm running PHP7 on IIS8 on Windows Server 2012 R2. Up to yesterday everything was fine as I only had 1 PHP website hosted, I started to host a second website and now php works on only one website at a time. 
If I restart IIS and visit one website it works but the other one won't (error 500) so I restart again and visit the non working one first and it works but the other one stops working (error 500).

So both websites are obviously correctly configured... Something in cgi maybe? I thought it might be the max instances (it was se to 1) so i set it to 0 but that didn't work. I put it back to 1 now otherwise it gives some headaches with the windows cache.

Any ideas how to have both working at the same time?
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

Ran into same problem on a *PHP7.1 / IIS8.5 / Win8.1* dev setup. With multiple websites only one would work. Accessing any of the others or even just the default *phpinfo* view would throw

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php7\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Module             FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler            php-7.1.1
Error Code         0x000000ff
```

Eventually could only solve it by **switching Application Pool identities to LocalSystem**. Even granting *IIS_IUSRS* and *IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool* full control permissions on site and PHP folders didn't do jack.